# Why is this DISTINCT/INNER JOIN/ORDER BY postgresql query so slow?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

This query takes ~4 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "resources_resource"."id",
                  "resources_resource"."heading",
                  "resources_resource"."name",
                  "resources_resource"."old_name",
                  "resources_resource"."clean_name",
                  "resources_resource"."sort_name",
                  "resources_resource"."see_also_id",
                  "resources_resource"."referenced_passages",
                  "resources_resource"."resource_type",
                  "resources_resource"."ord",
                  "resources_resource"."content",
                  "resources_resource"."thumb",
                  "resources_resource"."resource_origin"
  FROM "resources_resource"
  INNER JOIN "resources_passageresource" ON ("resources_resource"."id" = "resources_passageresource"."resource_id")
  WHERE "resources_passageresource"."start_ref" >= 66001001
  ORDER BY "resources_resource"."ord" ASC, "resources_resource"."sort_name" ASC LIMIT 5
```

By popular request, EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Limit  (cost=1125.50..1125.68 rows=5 width=803) (actual time=4434.076..4434.557 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=1125.50..1136.91 rows=326 width=803) (actual time=4434.076..4434.557 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=1125.50..1126.32 rows=326 width=803) (actual time=4434.075..4434.075 rows=6 loops=1)
              Sort Key: resources_resource.ord, resources_resource.sort_name, resources_resource.id, resources_resource.heading, resources_resource.name, resources_resource.old_name, resources_resource.clean_name, resources_resource.see_also_id, resources_resource.referenced_passages, resources_resource.resource_type, resources_resource.content, resources_resource.thumb, resources_resource.resource_origin
              Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 424kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=697.00..1111.89 rows=326 width=803) (actual time=3.453..41.429 rows=424 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (resources_passageresource.resource_id = resources_resource.id)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on resources_passageresource  (cost=10.78..190.19 rows=326 width=4) (actual time=0.107..0.401 rows=424 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (start_ref >= 66001001)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resources_passageresource_start_ref  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=326 width=0) (actual time=0.086..0.086 rows=424 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (start_ref >= 66001001)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=431.32..431.32 rows=2232 width=803) (actual time=3.228..3.228 rows=2232 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 947kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on resources_resource  (cost=0.00..431.32 rows=2232 width=803) (actual time=0.002..1.621 rows=2232 loops=1)
Total runtime: 4435.460 ms
```

This is ORM-generated SQL. I can work in SQL, but I'm definitely not proficient, and the EXPLAIN output here is mystifying to me. What about this query is dragging me down?

**UPDATE:** @Ybakos identified that the `ORDER_BY` was causing trouble. Removing the `ORDER_BY` clause altogether helps a bit, but the query still takes 800ms. Here's the EXPLAIN ANALYZE, sans `ORDER_BY`:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1122.49..1125.75 rows=326 width=803) (actual time=787.519..787.559 rows=104 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=697.00..1111.89 rows=326 width=803) (actual time=3.381..7.312 rows=424 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (resources_passageresource.resource_id = resources_resource.id)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on resources_passageresource  (cost=10.78..190.19 rows=326 width=4) (actual time=0.095..0.686 rows=424 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (start_ref >= 66001001)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resources_passageresource_start_ref  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=326 width=0) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=424 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (start_ref >= 66001001)
        ->  Hash  (cost=431.32..431.32 rows=2232 width=803) (actual time=3.173..3.173 rows=2232 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 947kB
              ->  Seq Scan on resources_resource  (cost=0.00..431.32 rows=2232 width=803) (actual time=0.002..1.568 rows=2232 loops=1)
Total runtime: 787.678 ms
```

Comment: do you have an `Index` on this fields? `resources_resource.id` and  `resources_passageresource.resource_id`

Comment: johntotetwoo has a good question. Your WHERE clause is hitting the index on resources_passageresource.start_ref... what about those cost values?

Comment: What is the output of ANALYZE?

Comment: Individual indices on `resources_resource.ord` and `.id`, as well as individual indices on `resources_passageresource.resource_id` and `.start_ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, `DISTINCT` has to be used to remove duplicates produced by the join. So my question is, why produce the duplicates in the first place? I'm not entirely sure what this query's being ORM-generated must imply, but if rewriting it is an option, you could certainly rewrite it in such a way as to prevent duplicates from appearing. For instance, using `IN`:

```
SELECT "resources_resource"."id",
       "resources_resource"."heading",
       "resources_resource"."name",
       "resources_resource"."old_name",
       "resources_resource"."clean_name",
       "resources_resource"."sort_name",
       "resources_resource"."see_also_id",
       "resources_resource"."referenced_passages",
       "resources_resource"."resource_type",
       "resources_resource"."ord",
       "resources_resource"."content",
       "resources_resource"."thumb",
       "resources_resource"."resource_origin"
  FROM "resources_resource"
  WHERE "resources_resource"."id" IN (
        SELECT "resources_passageresource"."resource_id"
          FROM "resources_passageresource"
          WHERE "resources_passageresource"."start_ref" >= 66001001
        )
  ORDER BY "resources_resource"."ord" ASC, "resources_resource"."sort_name" ASC LIMIT 5
```

or using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT "resources_resource"."id",
       "resources_resource"."heading",
       "resources_resource"."name",
       "resources_resource"."old_name",
       "resources_resource"."clean_name",
       "resources_resource"."sort_name",
       "resources_resource"."see_also_id",
       "resources_resource"."referenced_passages",
       "resources_resource"."resource_type",
       "resources_resource"."ord",
       "resources_resource"."content",
       "resources_resource"."thumb",
       "resources_resource"."resource_origin"
  FROM "resources_resource"
  WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM "resources_passageresource"
          WHERE "resources_passageresource"."resource_id" = "resources_resource"."id"
            AND "resources_passageresource"."start_ref" >= 66001001
        )
  ORDER BY "resources_resource"."ord" ASC, "resources_resource"."sort_name" ASC LIMIT 5
```

And, of course, if it's acceptable to rewrite the query completely, I would also remove the long table names in front of column names. Consider the following, for instance (the `IN` query rewritten):

```
SELECT "id",
       "heading",
       "name",
       "old_name",
       "clean_name",
       "sort_name",
       "see_also_id",
       "referenced_passages",
       "resource_type",
       "ord",
       "content",
       "thumb",
       "resource_origin"
  FROM "resources_resource"
  WHERE "resources_resource"."id" IN (
        SELECT "resource_id"
          FROM "resources_passageresource"
          WHERE "start_ref" >= 66001001
        )
  ORDER BY "ord" ASC, "sort_name" ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Sorry, should do what? Internally replace the join with `IN` when the `DISTINCT` clause is present and you are pulling rows only from one of the two tables and (probably) including the PK column?

Comment: Matching these two kinds of query with each other involves several factors, so it may not be an easy thing to teach a query planner to do, I guess. I don't know much about query planners as a software class, though. But you can say at least that PostgreSQL's one isn't smart enough (yet?).

Answer (score 1):

It's the combination of ORDER BY with LIMIT.

If you don't have an index on (ord, sort_name) then I bet this is the cause of the slow performance. Or perhaps an index on (start_ref, ord, sort_name) is necessary for this particular query. Lastly, due to that join, perhaps have the left/first table be the one upon which your ORDER BY criteria applies.

Comment: The planner is estimating 326 rows to sort in order by... should be milliseconds not seconds.  OP needs to post EXPLAIN ANALYZE for better picture.

Comment: Also it needs to sort for the Unique pass to implement DISTINCT. ordered index scans are not always better than seq scans + sort, in fact they can often be much worse due to seek times.

Comment: I have an index on `ord`, but not on `sort_name`, and I don't think I really need to sort on `sort_name` anyway. I'll try removing it.

Comment: Removing only `sort_name` from the ORDER BY doesn't help, but removing the ORDER BY altogether brings the query down to 800ms. A marked improvement, but still unacceptably slow.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a long time in the JOIN. The default memory settings in postgresql.conf are too low for any modern computer. Have you remembered to bump them up?